# Why is a Static Cast necessary to avoid overflowing int in a mathematical operation when the result will be stored in a variable large enough?

Tags: c++, static-cast

I have two integers, `m` and `k`. The product of `m` and `k` might overflow an `int` datatype, so I used `long long int` data type but I was still getting runtime error:

```
signed integer overflow: 89945 * 32127 cannot be represented in type 'int' (solution.cpp)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior prog_joined.cpp:14:28.
```

However when I used,

```
long long int b = static_cast<long long>(m) * static_cast<long long>(k);
```

it worked! So my doubt is why is casting `m` and `k` into `long long int` mandatory here?

Comment: An operation on two `int`s will produce an `int` BEFORE it is stored in the larger type. You need to force the conversion to the larger type (on at least one participant) before performing the operation.

Comment: When asking questions on Stack Overflow, show the code that does not work, not the code that does work (except for additional information). When people go looking for a problem in your code, they need to look in the code that does not work, not in the code that does work.

Comment: ^ I didn't vote to close as a duplicate (surely this has already got a good answer on the site) or formally answer it myself because I had to guess at where the mistake was. If you know the rules, it's the most logical guess, and it turned out to be the right one, but it's still just a guess.